# Select a checkbox by comparing two arrays

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to check a checkbox on a page by comparing two arrays. If a value exist in both the arrays then check the checkbox whose id is same as the matched value.
 (The array contains the Id of the Checkbox element.)
Even though the value exist in both the  the checking of the checkbox is not working.

Below is a link to jsfiddle with HTML and jquery

[JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zhEB2/7/) `J`

Comment: Wow, that's nice. Do you have a question?

Comment: can you elaborate more in details??

Comment: on which event you are firing ur javascript code and please check [prop in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). as it is either .prop("checked") or .prop({"checked":true}), it is not .attr that can be written as.attr("checked","checked"). and please enhance your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/zhEB2/9/

First of all it should be `$('.divPrintDetailed table')` instead of `$(#divPrintDetailed table')` and for iterating in the `idArray` first parameter is index and second is the element.

**JS:-**

```
function CheckboxSelect() {
    var idArray = [];
    var idContainerArray = [];

    idContainerArray[0] = "tbl-10-486011";
    idContainerArray[1] = "tbl-10-486013";
    idContainerArray[2] = "tbl-10-486016";

    $('.divPrintDetailed table').each(function (i, e) {
        idArray.push($(e).attr('id'));
    });

    //alert(idArray.length);

    $.each(idArray, function (index, el) {
        alert(el.slice(4));
        if ($.inArray(el, idContainerArray) != -1) {
            $('#' + el.slice(4)).prop("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
}

$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    CheckboxSelect();
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="divPrintDetailed">
    <table  id="tbl-10-486011" data-ordernum="0">
   <tr>    <td> 
     <input class="containerToCopy" id="10-486011" type="checkbox">   </td>       </tr>
        </table>
         <table  id="tbl-10-486012" data-ordernum="1">
             <tr>    <td>  <input class="containerToCopy" id="10-486012" type="checkbox">     </td>       </tr>
             </table>
         <table  id="tbl-10-486013" data-ordernum="2">
             <tr>    <td>  <input class="containerToCopy" id="10-486013" type="checkbox">     </td>       </tr>
             </table>
         <table  id="tbl-10-486014" data-ordernum="3">
             <tr>    <td>  <input class="containerToCopy" id="10-486014" type="checkbox">     </td>       </tr>
             </table>
         <table  id="tbl-10-486015" data-ordernum="4">
             <tr>    <td> <input class="containerToCopy" id="10-486015" type="checkbox">      </td>       </tr>
             </table>
         <table  id="tbl-10-486016" data-ordernum="5">
             <tr>    <td> <input class="containerToCopy" id="10-486016" type="checkbox">      </td>       </tr>
             </table>
             </div>
             <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" >Click Me!</button>
```